# How To Store Tamil Font in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "Insert into tbl (name) VALUES ('ஆன்லைனில்')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

But Its Store Db in
       à®†à®©à¯à®²à¯ˆà®©à®¿à®²à¯

Comment: convert utf-8 or utf-16

Comment: Obligatory JoelOnSoftware: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: My table Structure
SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

SET NAMES utf8mb4;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl`;
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the column format

```
ALTER `tbl` CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL;
```

Comment: Sir Again Save à®†à®©à¯à®²à¯ˆà®©à®¿à®²à¯ this format

Comment: Previous data you won't get back

Comment: add TABLE in between ALTER and table name Ex: ALTER TABLE `tbl`

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE `sample`.`sample_table` 
CHARACTER SET = utf8 ;

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE `mst_lyrics` CHANGE `lyrics_title` `lyrics_title` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Harish Karam Have a look here on how to readably format your posts. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Also, please augment your code-only answer with some explanation, in order to help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.